# Getting a ConcurrentModificationException but I'm not removing

Tags: java, android, concurrency, synchronization

What am I getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` with this code? I have a synchronized(listeners) lock.

```
private void notifyListeners(MediumRendition rendition) {
    if (rendition == null) return;
    synchronized (listeners) {
        for (RenditionEventListener l : listeners) {
            if (l.renditionType.equals(rendition.getType()) && l.mediumId == rendition.getMediumId()) {
                l.listener.onRendition(rendition);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void put(String renditionType, long mediumId, MediumRendition rendition) {
    HashMap<Long, MediumRendition> l = list.get(renditionType);
    if (l == null) {
        l = new HashMap<Long, MediumRendition>();
        list.put(renditionType, l);
    }
    l.put(mediumId, rendition);
    notifyListeners(rendition);
}

public void addRenditionListener(String renditionType, long mediumId, RenditionListener listener) {
    synchronized (listeners) {
        listeners.add(new RenditionEventListener(renditionType, mediumId, listener));
    }
}
```

> 01-30 16:47:55.147  6953  6974 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread 1
>   01-30 16:47:55.147  6953  6974 E AndroidRuntime: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   01-30 16:47:55.147  6953  6974 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
>   01-30 16:47:55.147  6953  6974 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.*.vos.RenditionList.notifyListeners(RenditionList.java:79)
>   01-30 16:47:55.147  6953  6974 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.t*.vos.RenditionList.put(RenditionList.java:41)
>   01-30 16:47:55.147  6953  6974 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.*.controllers.OmwController$6.run(OmwController.java:212)

SOLVED: Apparently I was removing. See below.

Comment: [`CME`s (docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) don't have to be caused by a *different* thread.

Comment: What else accesses listeners? Is it also synchronized?

Comment: ... so if that is the case here, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception indicates that listeners might have been modified from another thread. So you should check if it is being modified without synchronization somewhere else.

Also check if the implementation of onRendition() removes listener from list as that could be another cause if multiple threads are not involved.

Comment: "Also check if the implementation of onRendition() removes listener from list as that could be another cause if multiple threads are not involved...." Yeah, that's it. Thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 2):

Concurrency is kind of tricky. In the context of your application, though, you may not see that you are not modifying the list but it is getting modified somewhere when you call

```
l.listener.onRendition(rendition);
```

The possible solutions are as below.

1. Use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead of `ArrayList`. You don't need to write synchronize block if you use this collection. This is the simplest solution.
2. If 1. doesn't work, you can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of `ArrayList`.  When you stash listeners, it is preferable way to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that CopyOnWriteArrayList is preferable for listeners.